# Fetching node view to be used in backbone view

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I am working on a medium - large node/backbone app. For this reason, myself and the other dev I am working with have decided to use node views to keep our code clean.

Any information on what would be required to fetch the view and render it into a backbone view would be very helpful.

Thanks so much.

-Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node to serve the templates for backbone, having a route for each template, you might end up with a lot of parallel requests.

Anyway you simply could load templates async as described here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/09/asynchronously-load-html-templates-for-backbone-views/

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  template: 'my-view-template',

  render: function(){
    var that = this;
    //fetch your template from whereever
    $.get("/templates/" + this.template, function(template){
      var html = $(template).tmpl();
      that.$el.html(html);
    });
    return this;
  }

});
```